# Flat files in Informatica PowerCenter

Tags: sql, informatica-powercenter, flat-file

There are 2 flat files. These files has no common column.
Flat file 1 has 10 records, Flat file 2 has 5 records. I want 4 different targets :

1. 10 records from file 1
2. 5 records from file 2
3. 15 records from both the files
4. 50 records (like cross join)

Answer (score 1):

I am attaching a hand-drawn picture.

- 10 records from file 1 - Straight from SQ 1 to target 1 5 records
- 5 from file 2 - Straight from SQ 2 to target 2
- 15 records from both the
  files - UNION SQ1 and SQ2 and push to target 3
- 50 records (like cross
  join) - Use a joiner to join SQ1 and SQ2 and push to target 4. Join
  condition will be a dummy column with same value.

[image]